# How can I implement a UIViewcontroller thread safe singleton when I use storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, singleton

I need that one ViewController of my app is a singleton. I'm using storyboard.

I used this code:

```
    - (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}

static id s_singleton = nil;
+ (id) alloc {
    if(s_singleton != nil)
        return s_singleton;
    return [super alloc];
}
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(s_singleton != nil)
        return s_singleton;
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        s_singleton = self;
    }
    return self;
```

Maybe it is not thread safe because it creates two different instance of the class...
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Singletons are a bad idea.  Singleton view controller sounds doubly bad.  You should decouple whatever it is that is making a singleton view controller a requirement

Comment: Yes but this is a MapKit view and I want to avoid the reload and localization of the map. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Let map kit worry about that. If your view is in a navigation stack then it will be kept in memory anyway